# Are there any limitations using Active Directory on a Windows 7 setup running on VMWare player?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, vmware, active-directory

I want to use Active Directory on a Windows 7 installation setup running on VMWare on Ubuntu  11.10. Are there any limitations on this setup regarding the Active Directory usage?

Answer (score 1):

No there is no such restriction. It will be Similar to a windows Machine.